# Send Email via Macro in 'Rules and Alerts'

Tags: vba, outlook, rules

I want to send a custom email via 'Rules and Alerts' in Outlook 2007.

```
Sub SpirentBoxcarEmail()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objOutlookMsg As Object

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With objOutlookMsg
    .To = "me@email.com"
    .Subject = "Test"
    .Body = "Test"
    .Send
End With

Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

I know I need to add something like 'item As Outlook.MailItem' into the () of the Sub Title for the macro to show up under 'Scripts'

However, do I actually need to assign anything to this 'item'?

The macro runs just fine without the 'item' added but once I add 'item As Outlook.MailItem' and the Rule executes the script(macro), the email does not get sent out.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange, works for me with a received message rule.  Can you set a breakpoint in the procedure and see if the script is actually executing?

Answer (score 0):

I think outlook is looking for a specific function signature.  The rule expects to pass the current mail item to the macro.  Try this.

```
Sub SpirentBoxcarEmail(ByRef t As MailItem)

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objOutlookMsg As Object

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With objOutlookMsg
    .To = "me@email.com"
    .Subject = "Test"
    .Body = "Test"
    .Send
End With

Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written the RunAScript code as though it did not depend on an item being received.

Open a mailitem and run SpirentBoxcarEmail_RunAScript_Test

```
Sub SpirentBoxcarEmail_RunAScript(item As mailitem)

'Dim objOutlook As Object
'Dim objOutlookMsg As Object

Dim objOutlookMsg As mailitem

' Normally the trigger item is processed in some way.

MsgBox "The subject of the received mail that triggered the script is: " & _
    vbCr & vbCr & item.Subject

'  In this case the trigger item will now be ignored.

'Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = CreateItem(0)

With objOutlookMsg
    .To = "me@email.com"
    .Subject = "Test"
    .body = "Test"
    .Send
End With

Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
'Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub SpirentBoxcarEmail_RunAScript_Test()

' Open mail that fulfills the conditions of the rule
' This simulates mail being received

Dim currItem As mailitem
Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
SpirentBoxcarEmail_RunAScript currItem

End Sub
```